# app support libraries in Fragment Android

Tags: android, fragment, android-support-library

I've been having some issues with the support libraries, I am trying to call a fragment from a activity but it keep saying that the fragment class I created does not support a cast to app.support.v4 or "incompatible types" the thing is I don't know how to make the fragment class I created compatible with v4, here is where the error is:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.blitzar.stiktag.ImageSliderFragment;
import com.blitzar.stiktag.R;

public class ItemDescriptionActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private Fragment contentFragment;
ImageSliderFragment imageSliderFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_description);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(ImageSliderFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID) != null) {
            imageSliderFragment = fragmentManager
                    .findFragmentByTag(ImageSliderFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
            contentFragment = imageSliderFragment;
        }
    } else {
        imageSliderFragment = new ImageSliderFragment();
        switchContent(imageSliderFragment, ImageSliderFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
    }
```

This is the block of code that is molesting:

```
imageSliderFragment = fragmentManager
                    .findFragmentByTag(ImageSliderFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
            contentFragment = imageSliderFragment;
```

ImagSliderFragment is a fragment class i created, please any help will be highly regarded, thanks!

Comment: Post your ImageSliderFragment code. It has to extend android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fragment class make sure import is 
`android.support.v4.app.Fragment`;

Comment: Thanks it helped me with this line:
  imageSliderFragment = new ImageSliderFragment(); 
but still getting the one above

Comment: I had to do a cast on that line, now is working fine, thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Check your file of `ImageSliderFragment`

it should have a line

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

change it to

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```